# acceptance test method visit undefined

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4, laravel-dusk

I have created a new laravel 5.4 project with authentication.

I have then created a feature test for the login process which is as follows

```
public function test_login()
  {
    $user = factory(\App\User::class)->make();
    $user->save();
    $this->visit('/login')
    ->type($user->email,'email')
    ->type($user->password,'password')
     ->press('login');;
     $this->seePageIs('/dashboard');
    }
```

but when i run the test I get

Error: Call to undefined method Tests\Feature\UserTest::visit()

not sure if I need to install another component. this is what my composer.json looks like

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "laravel/dusk": "^1.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7"

    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you extended the `\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no `visit` method built-in by default in Laravel 5.4 You need to run `get` in order to run action but please be aware it is not working the same (probably no redirections are followed).

If you want to use old behaviour you can  use for now Laravel browser kit;

```
composer require laravel/browser-kit-testing
```

You can read more about it in migration guide: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade#upgrade-5.4.0

As another alternative you can use [Laravel Dusk](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/dusk) to run full browser tests

Comment: ahh that explains it. THanks.

Answer (score 8):

**Option 1**

The `visit` and `see` method no longer works in Laravel 5.4 by default. You need to install Laravel Dusk package.

```
composer require --dev laravel/dusk

php artisan dusk:install
```

So you can use `visit` and `assertSee` method respectively.

> For more info refer to laravel documentation [Laravel Dusk
>   Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/dusk)

**Option 2**

Sometimes you already have written test cases and you don't want to mess up with that then just install this package. It requires minimal configuration.

```
composer require laravel/browser-kit-testing --dev
```

> For more info refer [Laravel Browserkit Testing](https://github.com/laravel/browser-kit-testing#laravel-browserkit-testing)